# How to generate random IP address of a specific country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geoip, rails-geocoder

I was wondering if there is a way to use GeoIP gem and generate a random IP-address of a specific country.

Something like GeopIP.random_ip('IN') should output '183.82.121.911'.

Any help.

Comment: I have found a useful command line tool for the same: GeoIP-gen. https://code.google.com/p/geoipgen/

This generates N number of random IP addresses based on the country.